# Opening an image

Tags: java, image-processing, io, javax.imageio

I am an idiot. Why can't I read any files?

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class mainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Image picture = ImageIO.read(new File("picture.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

And the file is in the src folder for sure.

But it throws the exception everytime even though the file is there, no misspellings.

edit: The first sentence was true, I didn't put the image in the root.

Comment: Are you getting an error? What happens?

Comment: yes, it throws the exception everytime. That is all the code I have in the program too.

Comment: What exception does it throw?  Also the src folder doesn't mean that it's going to be found.. it needs to be in the runtime folder.  How are you running it?

Comment: I am using eclipse and I run it from there. All I did was stick the image file in the src folder.

Comment: The image file should go into the root of your eclipse project, not in the src/ folder. Also please post the stacktrace

Comment: Yeah it worked. My brain told me I tried that 3 hours ago. I obviously didn't. Thanks for the defrag.

Answer (score 3):

Been there as well, know that feeling. Anyway, try print out current working directory and that will tell you *exactly* where is the application really read from.

```
try
{
    Image picture = ImageIO.read(new File("picture.png"));
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    System.out.println("Current working directory : " + workingDir);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Relevant reference: [java.io.file docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

Also, using `absolute path` (like `/home/Stuff/Pictures/picture.png`) worth a shot. In other hand , it's OS dependent.

Note: `File` object has an [`getParent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParent()) method, which, in this case,  might do the same.

Comment: Okay, that's a very constructive comment and that's positive. Lately, no idea why SO deducted user reputation without giving good reason. Lost my faith toward SO to actively contribute in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the path of your image. For example:

```
Image picture = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Desktop/picture.png"));
```

Or if the image is in your workspace, for example:

```
Image picture = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/workspace/Project/src/picture.png"));
```

You can see the image location (the path of your image) clicking with the right button of the mouse in the image, then Properties.

You can use one slah ( / ) or two backslashs ( \\ ) to separate the directories of the path.

Answer (score 0):

There is a dichotomy in java.

1. If your file is part of the deliverable project, a file which can be packed in the application jar file, then it is a ***resource***.

   ```
   Image picture = ImageIO.read(SomeClassOfYours.class.getResource("/picture.png"));
   ```

The path is relative to that class, and can be made an absolute path. All on the java class path of the application.

2. If your file is a ***file system file***, a `File`, then the path best is a full absolute path. A relative path depends at which working directory the application is run, and that might differ.

   ```
   Image picture = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/.../src/picture.png"));
   ```

The question seems to indicate that the image is a read-only part of the application, in which case it is a resource file. The path *must* be case sensitive, and the path separator *must* be a forward slash `/`.

Answer (score 0):

The `ImageIO.read()` function will check whether an image is corrupted or not. If it's corrupted, it will throw an exception.

```
ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Desktop/picture.jpeg"));
```